# REST with Flask on a server Register

Tags: python, rest, flask, server

I'm studying Flask, I have a server on register.it that I use for my experiments. I created a phyton file with the classical Hello world! (the original code was more complicated but I've tried to reduce it to find the error), and a frontend page that requests the string using jquery POST.
Everything seems to work fine, no errors, neither if I run the code directly from the terminal. But instead of printing Hello world! the response is always:

It works!

Python 3.7.8

Have you an idea of what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: can you show the code. because we are unable to find the error without the code

Comment: Of course, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, sorry :)

This is in a file called REST.py in the folder ./REST/

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Hello, World!"
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And this one is the function in the front end file, in the folder ./

```
function search(qry, inc){
       data = {};
       data.qry = qry;
       data.inc = inc;
       $.post(
           './REST/',
           data,
           function(ret){
               try {
                alert(ret);
                //_results_list = JSON.parse(ret);
                //UI_searchresults(_results_list);
               }
               catch (e){
                alert(`C'é stato un errore di comunicazione con il server, ti invitiamo a provare piú tardi o a contattare l'assistenza`);
               }
           });
   }
```

I thought this should print the response, and it works but the response is always "It works! Python 3.7.8" instead of the string/json that I'd like to send. The code now is very easy so I don't have ideas about the possible problems.

Comment: you url is wrong in the post request it should be `/`

Comment: But they are in different folder, the REST.py is in a subfolder called REST. I tried with / only and the response is <!-- -->. What that I don't really undestrand is from where these string comes, because they are not random

Comment: You have not added the methods to the function `@app.route("/",methods=["POST","GET"])`